# Android; is a ListView the best approach to displaying multiple, independant progress bars?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-listview, android-progressbar

I have a requirement to display multiple linear progress bars on my UI. These will display wifi signal strengths.

If you're in a built up area, chances are you'll detect more than one wifi network, therefore I need to have a progress bar for each one which displays the signal strength.

My initial idea was to display these in a ListView, with the wifi name and the progress bar underneath.

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a better method I should be looking at for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` anyway is a good choice, but it has some drawbacks, since ListView is intented to be used with selectable items. In your case I suggest you don't need selections of items.

I would suggest to use another approach: `TableLayout` wrapped in `ScrollView` with dynamically added `TableRow`s. In this case you don't need of unnecessary `ListView`'s overhead

Comment: If I were to say that I do need to "click" on an item (to view more details/perform some action on that network), would this change your advice?

Comment: Sure, that would change my advice, because in this case the only option to handle clicks would be intercepting events from each item, which is pain. But if click actions would be complicated (like showing additional menu or so) - it would be better to work w/o ListView. At least I'm doing such in my application, where depending on type of item I need to respond in different way.

Comment: If you have several click targets within a list item call setItemsCanFocus(true) on the list and manage focus within the item views. Don't forget keyboard/trackball/dpad navigation - touch is not the only input mechanism on Android. :)